# Creating device density independent BitmapDrawable from file

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, scaling

I'm getting a Bitmap from file (cached from web) and short of hard coding the device density I can't get it to draw at the correct size.

I'm using the image as a menu icon so I can't set the scale type as far as I'm aware.

I've tried this and got nowhere:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inScaled = true; //tried false too
opt.inDensity = 240;
opt.inTargetDensity = 240; //both tried at various settings
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.toString(), opt);
BitmapDrawable icon = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

I had more luck with:

```
icon.setTargetDensity((int) (100 * metrics.density)); //Also tried at various settings
```

but  unless I hard-code the actual device DPI I can't get good results.